# PyPDF2 only reading newline chars from pages

Tags: python, pypdf

I am reading text from a pdf file like so:

```
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file_obj)
page_count = pdf_reader.numPages
text = ''

for i in xrange(page_count):
    text += pdf_reader.getPage(i).extractText()
```

However the output is a long unicode object ONLY containing the `\n` chars. The file is NOT encrypted.

Any explanation for not being able to read the text from this file?